# How to flag a question when it contains no problem?

Tags: discussion, flagging

How to flag a question, which asks a problem which is not a problem at all? E.g. the poster asks help with a code which cannot be compiled, but the code simply can be compiled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could ask in a comment what the user precisely wants. And if that doesn't help, one can vote to close the question because it's "Unclear what you're asking".